# Unable to add selected webpart(s)

Tags: list, feature, web-part

I've created a Custom List ('Tooltips') in SharePoint.
After this I used [SPSource](http://spsource.codeplex.com) to reverse engineer the list into a feature.

After installing and activating this feature, I want to add this list in a WebPart zone.

When doing this, I get an error message :

**Tooltips: List View Web Part could not be added, list may be hidden.**

What's wrong with the list?

**feature.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Feature Id="70d49f3d-233a-482d-97e3-dcec2c236171"
         Title="MyApp - Tooltips"
         Description="Creates a Tooltips list which can be used for mouse-over texts in InfoPath and FormWrapper."
         Version="12.0.0.0"
         Hidden="FALSE"
         Scope="Web"
         DefaultResourceFile="core"
         ReceiverAssembly="MyApp.WebServices, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=1de0ffdb1fdf1b80"
         ReceiverClass="MyApp.WebServices.TooltipsReceiver"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <ElementManifests>
    <ElementManifest Location="elements.xml" />
    <ElementManifest Location="tooltips_manifest.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="Tooltips\schema.xml" />
    <ElementFile Location="Tooltips\DispForm.aspx" />
    <ElementFile Location="Tooltips\EditForm.aspx" />
    <ElementFile Location="Tooltips\NewForm.aspx" />
    <ElementFile Location="Tooltips\AllItems.aspx" />
  </ElementManifests>
</Feature>
```

**elements.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
</Elements>
```

**schema.xml**
[download schema.xml](http://cid-ff58a5e0db16681c.skydrive.live.com/self.aspx/.Public/SharePoint/List%20Feature/schema.xml)

Comment: Maybe post your feature.xml, elements.xml and schema.xml and we can try to reproduce the error.

Comment: OK, xml files added.

Comment: Ok I haven't checked it out yet but... Your elements.xml file is obviously empty. What I was after is your ListTemplate definition which I assume is in tooltips_manifest.xml?

A couple of other questions... What does your feature receiver do? Do your custom forms have any modifications?

Answer (score 0):

Order of operations?  Are you trying to add it to the zone before the list was created?

Comment: It's an existing list.

Answer (score 0):

I would check logs and safe control entry in web config file. For debugging SP issues check 
http://blog.thekid.me.uk/archive/2007/07/25/debugging-tips-for-sharepoint-and-wss-exceptions.aspx